# reg show progress of construction visually

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, html

I want to show the progress newly constructing Tower/ bridges visually like bar chart where as here new thing is instead of Bar one series need to be a real image of the tower/Bridges. is there is any method to do it . pl help

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of readymade controls you can find on the web (ie: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14422), or you can write one your own, maybe starting from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20146/Write-Your-Own-Bar-Chart-Winforms-User-Control

Have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65803/A-Guide-to-using-MSChart-for-NET